# Issues in reading a specfic field in a given row

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Im trying to get the corresponding title to the given ID using the code below

```
public String get_Title(int id){
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                APP_TITLE,
                },
                KEY_ROWID + "="  + id,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

                String Final = c.getString(0);

                return Final;

        }
```

I keep gettting exceptions caused by the index out of bounds. IM not good with cursors, so if anyone could help me out here. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must before `String Final = c.getString(0)` call `c.moveToFirst()` or `c.moveToNext()` and then it should works. Because `Cursor` is implicitly positioned **to position before first row** so you must at first move `Cursor` to first row and then you can get data from it.

**EDIT:**

---

**So it should be like this:**

```
if (c.getCount()) { // if there is some data
   c.moveToFirst();
   String Final = c.getString(0);
}
else {
   Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So you wrote that you not good in work with `Cursor` little introduction:

> If you execute any statement, always instance of Cursor class will be
>   returned. It's version of a database cursor, it is used in many
>   database systems.

```
Class Cursor have following few basic methods:
```

- getCount() - to get how many rows is in actual cursor
- moveToFirst(), moveToNext() etc. - for moving between rows
- getColumnNames() - to get column' names
- getColumnIndex() - to get the zero-based index for the given column
  name...
- getString(), getInt() etc. - to get data of requested column' index
- requery() - once again execute cursor
- close() - to release resources of cursor.
- and next...

More about work with cursors you find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

Regards